# Container background doesn't cover entire screen

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to re-design my website using div's (earlier it was designed using tables). A problem that I am facing is that the container background is limited to just the deaher of the page, although all the content is place in the container div.

Also, if I place any content in the "content" div, the "rightsidebar" slips to the bottom of the "content" div. Please help on both the issues.

My homepage.php code:

```
    <body>
<div class="container">
    <?php
    include "header1.php"
    ?>
        <div class="sidebarleft"><font class="common">
        <ul>
        <li style="font-weight:bold; font-size:26; align:center;">Categories</li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="pol_score_reset.php">Politics</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="ps_score_reset.php">Programming Skills</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="gk_score_reset.php">general knowledge</a></li>
        </ul></font>
        </div>



        <div class="sidebarright"><font class="common">
        <--Google Adsense Ad-->
        </font>
        </div>  

</div>  
</body>
```

header1.php:

```
    <div class="header">
<a href="homepage.php"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
    <div style="width:728px; height:20; float:right; margin-top:20px; margin-right:10px;">
    <-- Google AdSense Ad-->

    </div>
<br/>
    <table width="100%" border="10">
        <tr>
            <td width="16.7%"><a href="homepage.php"><em>Home</em></a></td>
            <td width="16.7%"><a href="aboutus.php?us">About us</a></td>
            <td width="16.7%"><a href="contactus.php?us">Contact us</a></td>
            <td width="16.7%"><a href="privacy policy.php?us">Privacy policy</a></td>
            <td width="16.7%"><a href="user_cp.php">Past Quizzes</a></td>
            <td width="16.7%"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
```

stylesheet:

```
    body
    {
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
    background-position: top left;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
        div.header{
        width:100%;
        }
        div.container{
        width:80%;
        height:100%;
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-right:10%;
        background:gray;
        display:block;
        }
        div.sidebarleft{
        width:20%;
        float:left;
        }
        div.contentmain{
        width:75%;
        float:left;
        }
        div.sidebarright{
        width:20%;
        float:right;
}
```

Comment: Would you you be able to provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I do suspect you need to place a new div after sidebarright with the css clear: both, that may solve your issue.

Comment: I am not adept with Javascript and cannot provide a fiddle. Can you explain a bit more? I am also including a link to the page. Do check it.

Comment: Try `body{background:url(images/background.jpg);background-size: cover;` and make sure that your background image is big enough to cover entire screen, or use some nice pattern ;)

Comment: @mdesdev I am not looking to expand this background image. I am looking to expand the background color of the 'container' div

Comment: I check your page, background cover entire screen 1920x1080px

Comment: No. Again, that would expand the background image. I have to expand the bgcolor of container

Comment: Okay.. I had to remove the height width position and float tags in the clearfix css that you suggested.. it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change HTML to:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php
    include "header1.php"
    ?>
        <div class="sidebarleft"><font class="common">
        <ul>
        <li style="font-weight:bold; font-size:26; align:center;">Categories</li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="pol_score_reset.php">Politics</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="ps_score_reset.php">Programming Skills</a></li>
        <li style="font-size:26;"><a href="gk_score_reset.php">general knowledge</a></li>
        </ul></font>
        </div>



        <div class="sidebarright"><font class="common">
        <--Google Adsense Ad-->
        </font>
        </div>  
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>  
</body>
```

And add to you css the following style:

```
.clearfix{
   clear: both;
}
```

This simple makes the containing div cover those divs you have floated left.

Comment: it worked.. thank you.. Can you please suggest a solution to my other problem too?